# copy excel cell copies carriage return also

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, copy-paste, carriage-return

I am copying individual cells from excel and pasting it into SQL. Each time I do it, carriage return is automatically added to copy.

**Repro:**

> Enter 123 in any cell in excel 2007.Click on another cell. Now
>   right click on the cell you just entered. Select copy. 
>   Open notepad and paste.
>   Note that carriage return is also copied, where there is no carriage
>   return in the cell.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'd want the carriage return if you were copying more than one cell, which is probably why it's being included.

But if you're copying one at a time, you can copy from the formula bar instead of from the cell then you won't get the carriage return.

If you have a *lot* of cells to copy, you might want to create a simple VBA script to push the contents of the selected cell into the clipboard (then assign that to a hotkey).

Edit:

Example macro:

```
Sub CopyActiveCell()
    Dim objData As MSForms.DataObject
    Set objData = New MSForms.DataObject
    objData.SetText ActiveCell.Value
    objData.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Note that for that to work you need to add a reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` (via Tools | References).  If you're copying many values, you could make it even simpler by adding creating the sub in the Sheet1 module as

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

instead of

```
Sub CopyActiveCell()
```

That will automatically copy the cell value whenever you click once on a cell to select it.